# Put currency number and postfix/prefix in h:inputText

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Can I put a number with a postfix/prefix in a `<h:inputText>`?

E.g.

<kbd>100.00 Euro</kbd>

or

<kbd>100.00 €</kbd>

Comment: Yes, you can: `<h:inputText value="#{bean.currencyValue} #{bean.currencyName}" disabled="true" />`

Comment: @Vasil: are you being sarcastic?

Comment: Sorry for that comment, I usually divide this kind of input to 2 parts: inputText for input Value and outputText or disabled selectOneListbox for additional info (currency name in this case).

Comment: Thanks. But when you put 2 values in the input, how to check if the currencyValue is a number?

Comment: You can create validator which will validate only 1st part of input. But I recommend you to use BalusC approach or move currency name in separate field (like outputText).